# Laptop has black screen and fans on when on battery power

Tags: laptop, battery, power

When trying to turn on my laptop using just the battery, the lights and fans run, but the screen and all other operations do not work.

When the power cord is plugged in, the laptop works fine. It will boot normally with or without the battery as long as the power cord is plugged in. If I unplug the cord while the computer is running, it will freeze in a couple of seconds.

I have tried a new battery and re-installing windows, which did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver specific problem. It relies on laptop manufacturer power management software. Can you give more details concerning the laptop?

For a more general answer:

- Check out the manufacturer support website for downloading updates of BIOS and fan driver;
- Check out on Internet to search for known problems;
- If possible, ask for support directly to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using laptop with **extend monitor** or projector when use battery to check if there are problem with power supply to laptop monitor. But I guess problem is your main board, it need to repair if needed.